# Set up CLASSPATH in windows cmd

Tags: bash, cmd, classpath, stanford-nlp

I want to run the following

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:javanlp-core.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar";
for file in `find lib -name "*.jar"`; do export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:`realpath $file`"; done
```

in Windows.. I downloaded [win bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) but when I run the above commands I get:

```
File not found - -NAME
```

Am I doing right or this is not the right way to execute the above commands?

Comment: Did you type `-NAME` instead of `-name`?  Do any of the files have embedded whitespace?  If so then you need quotes in `realpath "$file"`

Comment: No I typed it as the output, -NAME ....

Comment: @cdarke none of them have  embedded whitespace..

Comment: Even so, you should be careful to quote variables containing filenames, particularly on Windows.  The parameter to `find` should be `-name`, not `-NAME`.  Most things that come from UNIX are case sensitive.